# xamarin studio - android emulator not launching application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am trying to launch a simple application with some labels and images on the content page, but when the android emulator starts it opens the application and shows only a white page with nothing on it. However, if I run the iOS simulator it shows the label and images. So I wonder if there is something that is preventing the page from loading? I am using Xamarin Forms in Studio on Mac.

Comment: So the application is launching but not presenting your layout. Your title implies something different. Also, what have you done so far to locate a possible error? Please improve your question.

Comment: It started by not launching the application at all then, I changed the target framework to marshmallow 6.0 then then it opened the application but with nothing on the layer.

Comment: Try to run application on Android device connected to the Mac via USB. If app will work we know that something is wrong with emulator.

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere so we can have a look at it? Works on one platform doesn't imply it works on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it in a fisical device ?
Just to know if your emulator has an error...

Are you sure you have an StackLayout or another container for the label and entry ?

Hope you solve it...